# How can I put all graphs for different sample size `n=10, 100, 1000, 2000` in the same plot and change the color of `y=1` in red?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

For a sample size `n=1000`, I plot the following graph based the code

```
n = 1000; 
m = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[n], n]]; 
{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[m]; 
h = evec[[All, 1]]; 
imin = Ordering[eval, 1][[1]]; 
lambda2minlambda1 = Sort[eval][[2]] - Sort[eval][[1]]; 
tn = 1/(4*lambda2minlambda1);
```

Plot the function H1 (t)

```
Plot[Abs[h[[imin]]]*Exp[-2*eval[[imin]]*t]/Sqrt[Sum[h[[i]]^2*Exp[-4*eval[[i]]*t], {i, 1, n}]], 
{t, 0, 10*tn}, 
 GridLines -> {{tn}, {1}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[{Red, Blue}, Thickness[0.008]], 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Question:**

How can I put all graphs for different sample size `n=10, 100, 1000, 2000` in the same plot and change the color of `y=1` in red?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Show[Append[Table[
  m=RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[n], n]]; 
  {eval,evec}=Eigensystem[m];h=evec[[All,1]];imin=Ordering[eval,1][[1]]; 
  lambda2minlambda1=Sort[eval][[2]]-Sort[eval][[1]];tn=1/(4*lambda2minlambda1);
  Plot[Abs[h[[imin]]]*Exp[-2*eval[[imin]]*t]/Sqrt[Sum[h[[i]]^2*Exp[-4*eval[[i]]*t],
    {i,1,n}]],{t,0,10*tn},PlotRange->{{0,60},{0,1}}],
  {n,{10,100,1000,2000}}],
  Plot[1,{x,0,60},ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},Red]]],
  PlotRange->{{0,60},{0,1}}]
```

There are always at least a dozen different ways of doing anything in Mathematica. Pick one that you can remember and use without making any mistakes.